# Binding UserControl Dependency Properties to Runtime DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm quite new to xaml. I have looked around quite a bit and I'm finding posts that come close to what I'm trying to do, but I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have an external WPF UserControl with Dependency Properties. In another project, I've imported the dll from my UserControl library. I created a static grid in my project in which there is an instance of my usercontrol in each cell. Each UserControl DependencyProperty I've defined is available in xaml.

At runtime, I will fill a DataTable with data then I need to bind the UserControls in my grid to the DataTable, so that each UserControl reflects values from the DataTable. Each row in the DataTable will have several column values that I need to bind to my UserControl's Dependency Properties.

What I'm having trouble with is defining the DataContext after the data is retrieved in such a way that I can define a binding path for the Dependency properties in each one of my UserControls. If I set the DataContext of my grid to the DataTable like this:

```
Grid.DataContext = myDataTable;
```

Then what is the syntax for the binding path of the UserControl property?

```
<my:ucControl Name="myUserControl1" MyDependencyProp="{Binding Path=??}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

I've seen posts where some have used "Row[0][column_name]" or variations of that, but I can't seem to get anything like that working. Am I approaching the binding method wrong?

Here is my UserControl code:

```
 public partial class ucControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static DependencyProperty IndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Index", typeof(int), typeof(ucControl));


    public static DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(String), typeof(ucControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new       PropertyChangedCallback(NotifyPropertyChanged)));


    #region PublicProperties

    public int Index
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IndexProperty, value); }
    }

    public String Status
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }

#endregion
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid Canvas.Left="17" Canvas.Top="46" Name="MasterGrid" Width="1259" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Name="ColumnHeader" Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="DateColumn" Width="80"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <my:ucControl Name="myControl1" Index="{Binding ??}" Status="{Binding ??}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
            <my:ucControl Name="myControl2" Index="{Binding ??}" Status="{Binding ??}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
            <my:ucControl Name="myControl3" Index="{Binding ??}" Status="{Binding ??}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
        </Grid>
```

Here is my C#:

```
String strViewSelect = "SELECT index, status, FROM Table1 ORDER BY index ASC;
System.Data.DataSet dsMonthData = dataClass.mFillDataset(strViewSelect);

MasterGrid.DataContext = dsMonthData;
```

UPDATED: Here's how I've solved this issue:

First, I'm creating a static DataSource in my project that contains the columns that I want to bind to. Adding arguments to the query so I can specify the data that I want to retrieve.

The following was added to the XAML in my window:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <my1:myDataSet x:Key="myDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="tableNameViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=tableName, Source={StaticResource myDataSet}}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Next, I've added the following XAML to my grid:

```
DataContext="{StaticResource tableNameViewSource}"
```

Now, I can add the bindings to my UserControl properties:

```
Status="{Binding Path=statusColumn}"

<my:ucCalendarCell Name="ucControl1" Status="{Binding Path=statusColumnName}" Index="{Binding Path=indexColumnName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" />
```

A little bit of work left to tailor to my needs, but that's the basic idea. I'm positive that is more than one way to do this, but this should work for me.

Comment: post your full XAML and your code.

Comment: error 1: what you need is a DataGrid, not a regular Grid. How many of your usercontrols will you declare? what if the table has 10000000 rows?

Comment: error 2: do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged in DependencyObject-based classes (I.E UI Elements)

Comment: The table has a fixed number of rows and columns, with a fixed number of usercontrols.

Comment: @HighCore - Thanks for your tip on INotifyPropertyChanged. What I need to do is get an idea of how to set the DataContext and then the binding on the properties.

Comment: Still, this is an inappropiate way to implement this. Take a look at ItemsControl-derived classes such as ListBox